# Faker and Pandas | ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, faker

I am using **Faker**; a library for generating values for your mock datasets.

I am using **Jupyter Notebooks**.

The goal of this code is to generate specific fake data, under the condition of gender. E.g. so as "Mrs." and "Peter" don't get mixed together.

Error is in relation to how I am appending data to the dataframe.

Cell 1:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

import random

np.random.seed(42)
```

Cell 2:

```
def example_dataset_simulation(samples, cols):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(samples), columns=np.arange(cols))
    
    #for col in range(cols):
    for row in range(samples):       
        gender = random.randint(0, 1)
        
        df['Prefix'] = [fake.prefix_male() if gender == 0 else fake.prefix_female()]
        df['Forename'] = [fake.first_name_male() if gender == 0 else fake.prefix_female()]
        df['Surname'] = fake.first_name()  # unconditional
        df['Suffix'] = [fake.suffix_male() if gender == 0 else fake.suffix_female()]
    
    return df
```

Cell 3:

```
df = example_dataset_simulation(2, 2)
df
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot have **list notation** wrapping around my **if-conditional** *"outputs"*.

i.e. remove **'[]'**:

Original:

```
df['Prefix'] = [fake.prefix_male() if gender == 0 else fake.prefix_female()]
```

Now:

```
df['Prefix'] = fake.prefix_male() if gender == 0 else fake.prefix_female()
```